# "Exploding" objects apart evenly in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Just wondering if this is possible by some built in function or a plugin of some sort.

Basically, I need to take a group of objects, and 'explode' them apart evenly.

So, if I started with the 4 squares in the first image:
[image: four squares]

I need to 'explode' them apart by a certain amount, so that the gaps between them are evenly spaced. See second picture for illustration:

[image: spaced apart]

I would just select them one at a time and space them by moving them via the arrow keys, but I've got a few images that have hundreds of objects that this needs to be done to.

Comment: Maybe this is the [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117410/inkscape-breaking-object-apart?rq=1) you're searching for?

Comment: I'm not aware of an automatic way, but there could be some workarounds (see [here](https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopicb6ea.html?t=33456) or [here](https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic4dbe-2.html?t=16575)). Or you can move one of the objects and apply an [uniform distribution](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Align.html) (both horizontal and vertical) to all the objects. Or you can scale the whole group and then resize applying to each object separately... Try and let us know.

Answer (score 6):

You can open the Align and Distribute panel <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and use the "Remove overlaps" functionality, even though there are no overlaps.

1. Select all the objects
2. In the Align and Distribute panel, set the H and V values the same, say something like 50 for example, and hit the move button.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For non-rectangular geometry you can apply the following approach:

[image]

1. Select objects and open Object → Transform... → Scale
2. Scale down objects with checked 'Apply to each box separately' (e.g. 80%)
3. Scale up objects with unchecked 'Apply to each box separately' (e.g. 125%)

Note: in the last step you can write `10000/xx`, where `xx` is the percentage applied at step 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a common feature request.

To get this implemented, you could add your support to one of the linked issues from here:

https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/2619

https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/671

(There are probably more of that type in the tracker)